# How to start a remote PHP script via cronjob (alternative to wget)?

Tags: php, cron, wget

I need to start a remote PHP script (example.com/cron.php) every minute with a cronjob. At the moment, my cronjob looks like this: `wget example.com/cron.php`. This works, but puts a cron.php file on my server every time. How can I prevent this? Or are there alternatives to `wget`?

Comment: What is the PHP script you are trying to start?  If cron.php doesn't exist, where is the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from manpage for wget:

> `-O file`
>
> Use of `-O` is not intended to mean simply "use the name file instead of the one in the URL;" rather, it is analogous to shell redirection: `wget -O file http://foo` is intended to work like `wget -O - http://foo > file;` file will be truncated immediately, and all downloaded content will be written there.

That means that `-O -` redirects output to stdout. And output on stdout you can simply redirect to `/dev/null`:

```
wget -O - http://example.com/cron.php >/dev/null
```

Comment: *I need to start a remote PHP script (example.com/cron.php) **every minute** with a cronjob* -- your answer doesn't address that part.

Comment: @AmalMurali well, he says "This works, but…", so it doesn't seem that that is his problem.

Comment: As i said, it looks **like** this ;) Actually, my current cronjob starts the script every minute, but create one file for each call... ~44k files in one month. @bwoebi: thanks, works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

if your sever has lynx installed you could do `lynx example.com/cron.php` or you could use curl and do `curl example.com/cron.php`

Answer (score 0):

This solution is for linux server: 
To execute a cron job you need to have access to cronTab on the server:

to edit crontab use the commnad line :

```
sudo crontab -e
```

add a the script you would like to execute:

```
* * * * *  php /path/to/your/script/cron.php 2>&1
```

Save your crontab and you should be done.

Please check the link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron to understand the asterisk

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://www.setcronjob.com/

This web program enables you to automatically schedule cron jobs on other servers.